# Возможно ли использовать вычисляемое поле в mysql запросах для последующих вычислений в запросе?

Tags: mysql

Пример `mysql` запроса:

```
SELECT 
val_1 * val_2 / 100 AS val_p, 
val_1 * val_p AS val_x 
FROM mytable
```

Естественно получаю ошибку, что `val_p` не существует в таблице. Вопрос, можно ли как то вычисляемое сознанное поле `val_p` использовать дальше для формирования последующих вычислений?

Comment: можно, но на следующем уровне запроса `select val_p * val_1 from (ваш запрос) X where val_p>100`, например.

Comment: @Mike а как же переменные? или парсер запроса не поймет все равно?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Да ну их. не люблю их использовать, когда есть стандартный подход. в том же where же их не используешь. да и потом БД поменяют и привет. А парсер в принципе поймет без проблем `select @val_p:=val_1 * val_2 / 100 AS val_p, val_1 * @val_p AS val_x`

Comment: Большое спасибо, помогли!